# Can't Seem to Group By Month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have been searching for the logic behind how to work with dates in general, and in this case, group by dates.

I have a table that looks like the following:

[image: 85843]

I am currently trying to count the number of trips happening in 2016 and group by month, and my most recent attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%y-%m'), COUNT(id)
FROM
    trips
WHERE
    start_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY YEAR(start_date) , MONTH(start_date);
```

The error would be:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bixi.trips.start_date' which
> is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I haven't really got the hang of working with dates, like group by and such, and the sites I've found ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)) haven't been particularly useful.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Instead of the `DATE_FORMAT` You should try `YEAR(date_column), MONTH(date_column)` or change the group by to your current `DATE_FORMAT()` statement. The error is caused because you are performing an aggregate function on a string ( the `DATE_FORMAT()`) but trying to group the table by to integer values (the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty clear.  Just use the same expression in the `group by` as in the `select`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%y-%m'), COUNT(id)
FROM trips
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%y-%m');
```

I would also discourage you from using `BETWEEN`.  The logic is more safely written as:

```
WHERE start_date >= '2016-01-01' AND start_date < '2017-01-01'
```

This is safer because it works both for dates and datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select datePart(yy, start_date), datePart(mm, start_date), count(*)
from trips
where start_date >= '2016-01-01' and start_date < '2017-01-01'
group by datePart(yy, start_date), datePart(mm, start_date)
order by datePart(yy, start_date), datePart(mm, start_date)
```